# AndroidManifest complains Element Application(and MultiDexApplication) is not allowed here

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I am sorry if this seems like a duplicate post. Trust me it is not. I have searched all over stackoverflow and the internet but couldn't find any helpful solution.

Everything was fine till i added this line to my android studio

```
compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:1.0.0'
compile ‘com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1’
```

Then i realised that the app fails to build. Something about duplicate method declaration BarcodeFormat.class..... I replaced the second line with
`compile('com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.zxing', module: 'core'
    }`

I built and it was successful. Now, Application Tag is no longer recognized in AndroidManifest as well as all constituent Activity tags. So hence the launcher activity cannot be located on apk installation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ng.softworks.unorthodox.iretriever" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<MultiDexApplication
    android:name=".app.VolleyController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".activity.App_Splashscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.AddLostListing" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.AddFoundListing" >
    </activity>
</MultiDexApplication>
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ng.softworks.unorthodox.iretriever"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':volley')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:1.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:1.0.0'
compile('com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.zxing', module: 'core'
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Please help me. This is driving me nut as I can't find any specific error to tackle!

Comment: Why your manifest has a `MultiDexApplication` element instead of `application`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using Zing and QRCodeReaderView together initially messed up the project internals. I had to migrate to a new project and this time, added dependency for QRGen(with Zing's core.jar excluded) and QRCodereaderview. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate method declaration is due to com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:1.0.0 bundles its own version of zxing through [core.jar](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView/blob/master/QRCodeReaderView-lib/qrcodereaderview/libs/core.jar)

If you are going to use that lib, you should make sure that core.jar is excluded.

Either that or make sure zxing is not included elsewhere.

Comment: I added zing and QRCodereaderview initially. But then I had issues and had to remove zing and add QRGen. In the long run I tried all options but it failed, I then had to create a new project and manually migrate file, adding only QRGen and QRCodereader with (Zing core.jar excluded)